# Jinja/Flask iterating through a dictionary and passing values to a bootstrap carousel

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to iterate through a dictionary of dictionaries in python/jinja/flask and pass values into a bootstrap carousel. Something is hanging up, I've been hand-wringing and talking to ducky for hours because I'm a noob, so I'm going to ask for help from less bouncy folk.

```
portfolio_entries = {1: {"title": "Website",
                         "pic":"picture.png",
                         "link":"https://www.website.com/",
                         "description":"A website."}

@app.route("/portfolio")
def portfolio():
    return render_template("portfolio.html", all_sites=portfolio_entries)
```

From the template:

```
{% for site in all_sites %}
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{url_for('static', filename='../static/img/site.pic')}}" alt="{{site.title}}">
  <h1><a href="{{site.link}}" target="_blank">{{site.title}}</a></h1>
  <p>{{site.description}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary has a curly bracket missing at the end, so it should look like this:

```
portfolio_entries = {1: {"title": "Website",
                     "pic":"picture.png",
                     "link":"https://www.website.com/",
                     "description":"A website."}}
```

[Dictionaries in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) do not support the dot attributes. You have to use the indexing syntax i.e. two square brackets. Also, in your case, you have to access your nested dictionary items.

Here is what your code should look like:

```
{% for site in all_sites %}

<div class="carousel-item">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{url_for('static', filename='../static/img/site.pic')}}" alt="{{ all_sites[site]['title'] }}">
  <h1><a href="{{ all_sites[site]['link'] }}" target="_blank">{{ all_sites[site]['title'] }}</a></h1>
  <p>{{ all_sites[site]['description'] }}</p>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```